# Bass library: unable to open slave in linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, archlinux, alsa, bass

Here is code:

```
if (!BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, NULL, NULL)) {
    return 0;
}

DWORD chan = BASS_StreamCreateFile(FALSE, argv[1] , 0, 0, BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
BASS_ChannelPlay(chan, FALSE);
```

After compiling and running program i get following error:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: [Did you set your default audio output wrong?](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=123902)

Comment: [Loads of results on Google for this issue](https://dev.to/setevoy/linux-alsa-lib-pcmdmixc1108sndpcmdmixopen-unable-to-open-slave-38on)

Comment: I have already tried this solution. It helps, but after starting my program, the sound of other programs no longer works.

Comment: You should mention _everything_ you've done, in your question.